# How to save multiple audio files from one audio file based on speaker?

Tags: python, pyaudio, librosa, kaldi

I have an audio file in which there are 2 speakers, the first one recites a sentence & then the other one translates it.

I want to save an audio file for each sentence recited by speaker A & B.

Example:
file -> book_translation.mp3 ( 1minute audio )

> Speaker A: "How are you"
>
> Speaker B: "wie gehts"
>
> Speaker A: "I'm good"
>
> Speaker B: "Mir geht's gut"

Output expected:
4 mp3 files ->
A_01.mp3
B_01.mp3
A_02.mp3
B_02.mp3

Comment: You want to seperate the audio of both speakers?

Comment: yes, I want to split each sentence of both the speakers into different files

Comment: Seems like a cocktail party problem. But if both the speakers do not speak simultaneously you can just split the audio file when the second person starts speaking.

Comment: yes both the person doesn't speak simultaneously.

Comment: problem is I have more than 20hours of such audio file & I can't listen & split them

Comment: Take a look at this: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33291/audio-analysis-segment-audio-based-on-speaker-recognition

Comment: In general this is called Speaker Diarization, and can be complicated. But if there is periods of not speaking in between, you can cut them up based on the volume. Once you got those clips, then you can probably use clustering on Audio Embeddings to put them into two categories.

Comment: Here is a list of resources for Speaker Diarization, https://github.com/wq2012/awesome-diarization

Comment: @jonnor I am new to this, I tried using pyannote-audio but couldn't achieve the result because of less patience, I am looking for an easy breakthrough, also any tutorial with this will help

Comment: @Raj Thanks for the resource, will look into this

Comment: Hey @Raj thanks a lot for your help, at least I'm done with prototyping, have to work on 2 problems now, 1) Low Accuracy , 2) Noise added in sub audio files